# RabbitMQ Docker container not working on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ docker container running that is used by PHP AMQ Library with Docker compose.

When running locally on my laptop everything works fine and RabbitMQ can accept requests.

However when deploying to a t2.medium instance for testing, the RabbitMQ container keeps restarting and crashing every 40-50 seconds.

To make matters worse I cannot find the `erl_crash.dump` file in the EC2 instance.

```
   Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...
              RabbitMQ 3.6.14. Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: tty
  ######  ##        tty
  ##########
              Starting broker...

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:05 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.6.14 on Erlang 19.2.1
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:05 ===
node           : rabbit@bbee863f0066
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : o9UBS7q82y5P84WzdKnCaw==
log            : tty
sasl log       : tty
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@bbee863f0066
erl_child_setup closed

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...erl_child_setup closed

              RabbitMQ 3.6.14. Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: tty
  ######  ##        tty
  ##########
              Starting broker...

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:13 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.6.14 on Erlang 19.2.1
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:13 ===
node           : rabbit@bbee863f0066
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : o9UBS7q82y5P84WzdKnCaw==
log            : tty
sasl log       : tty
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@bbee863f0066

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:15 ===
Loading of /usr/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.2/ebin/dets_v9.beam failed: badfile
WARNING: module dets_v9 not found, so not scanned for boot steps.

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:15 ===
beam/beam_load.c(1179): Error loading module dets_v9:
  form size 113612 greater than size 82440 of binary

erl_child_setup closed

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...erl_child_setup closed

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...
              RabbitMQ 3.6.14. Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: tty
  ######  ##        tty
  ##########
              Starting broker...

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:05 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.6.14 on Erlang 19.2.1
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:05 ===
node           : rabbit@bbee863f0066
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : o9UBS7q82y5P84WzdKnCaw==
log            : tty
sasl log       : tty
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@bbee863f0066
erl_child_setup closed

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...erl_child_setup closed

              RabbitMQ 3.6.14. Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: tty
  ######  ##        tty
  ##########
              Starting broker...

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:13 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.6.14 on Erlang 19.2.1
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:13 ===
node           : rabbit@bbee863f0066
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : o9UBS7q82y5P84WzdKnCaw==
log            : tty
sasl log       : tty
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@bbee863f0066

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:15 ===
Loading of /usr/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.2/ebin/dets_v9.beam failed: badfile
WARNING: module dets_v9 not found, so not scanned for boot steps.

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:15 ===
beam/beam_load.c(1179): Error loading module dets_v9:
  form size 113612 greater than size 82440 of binary

erl_child_setup closed

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...erl_child_setup closed

              RabbitMQ 3.6.14. Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: tty
  ######  ##        tty
  ##########
              Starting broker...

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:22 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.6.14 on Erlang 19.2.1
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:22 ===
node           : rabbit@bbee863f0066
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : o9UBS7q82y5P84WzdKnCaw==
log            : tty
sasl log       : tty
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@bbee863f0066
erl_child_setup closed

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...erl_child_setup closed

              RabbitMQ 3.6.14. Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: tty
  ######  ##        tty
  ##########
              Starting broker...

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::13:49:32 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.6.14 on Erlang 19.2.1
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
```

This is my docker compose file for Rabbit:

```
rabbit:
    mem_limit: 80000000
    build: 'support/rabbitmq'
    environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_USER}
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
        - RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK=800MB
    ports:
        - "15672:15672"
        - "5672:5672"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Any ideas why its not working, or how I can get this dump file?

Comment: provide docker container logs, docker logs container_id

Comment: Ok added the full logs I got from that

Comment: erl_crash.dump will not be in EC2 instance it will be under container directory, might be in /var/lib/rabbitmq folder or in root folder

Comment: Can't find it anywhere on the EC2 instance, I tried `find / -name erl_crash.dump`

Comment: As I told it will not be on EC2 instance, if it's created then it will be on container. Enter into container docker exec -it container_id then search in root folder or above mentioned paths

Comment: Thanks but it says "Container is restarting, wait until the container is running"
However it is stuck like this in a loop, I can't get access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160561/discussion-between-sanath-and-kaleeway).

Comment: Thanks, it was the `mem_limit` parameter that was causing an issue when starting, I removed it and rabbitMQ worked ok in AWS server with 4gb of VRAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to docker-compose `mem-limit` being incorrectly set

```
    mem_limit: 80000000
```

This setting is 80mb, which is not enough for RabbitMQ to initialise properly.

Removing this and letting docker_compose manage container memory was the solution.